# How to validate text and number within text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just need help from you guys to succeed the below SR number validation in 'onkeyup' event.

SR No eg :- MIN-015456

SR number contains with three permanent MIN letter set and a dash following 5 numbers from 0-9.totally 9 letters in the SR number set.

kindly suggest me a validation in jquery or JavaScript.

I have tried below code, but it wasn't successful:

```
$('#Sr_id').on('keyup', function () {
            var Sr_id_no = document.getElementById('Sr_id').value;
            if (/^[MIN]{1}[-][0-9]{5}$/.test(Sr_id_no) || Sr_id.length < 10) {
}
```

Comment: Those square brackets aren't being used correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your expression `^[MIN]{1}[-][0-9]{5}$` works is the following:

1. `^` Make sure this is the beggining of text
2. `[MIN]{1}` Match precisely `1` character from the following set: `M` OR `I` OR `N`
3. `[-]` Match 1 character (by default) from the following set: `-`
4. `[0-9]{5}` Match precisely `5` characters from the following set: `0`, `1`, ..., `8`, `9`
5. `$` Make sure this is the end of the expression

## What to do?

Always test your regular expressions with various inputs, live. I recommend the following site: http://regexr.com/3fga9 (see to test the expression below)

Also, here's your expression: `^MIN-\d{5}$`

`\d` means "any digit", so it is the same as writing `[0-9]`

Answer (score 0):

`[MIN]` basically means M or I or N (in any order) and `{1}` is occurrence of one.

What you want is this:

```js
console.log(/^MIN-[0-9]{5}$/.test("MIN-01545"))
```

Note: `MIN-015456` is 10 characters in total